# Replace parameters inside pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, templates

How do I supply Maven with properties and force it to actually replace them in the pom.xml file? E.g. I have a "template" pom.xml which I use for deploying packages and some dependencies. I want the `artifactId`, `version` and other variables to be replaced and the resulting `pom.xml` to be uploaded.

Using command-line arguments does not work, e.g. `mvn clean deploy -DartifactId=someArtifact` does upload the jar to the correct location, but the uploaded `pom.xml` contains the placeholder variables instead of their actual values.

Concrete example:

The POM file contains this definition of dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.avast.melka</groupId>
            <artifactId>${runtimeId}</artifactId>
            <version>${runtimeVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And I want Maven to deploy the corresponding package with POM containing something like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.avast.melka</groupId>
        <artifactId>actualIdValue</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.42</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How do I do that? The closest thing I could find was http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html - but this deals with replacing values in resource files, not POM, and to me it seems like a different usecase.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do that. The `maven-release-plugin` does something similar for the version... I guess you could create your own plugin based on what it does.

Comment: Why do you need templates for pom file for artifacts you are deploying ? Why not creating the ones and using it..apart from that why not using the maven build for that via `mvn deploy` ?

Comment: I want to use it automatically in a generic CI build job that can be instantiated by different teams in my company and customized to produce maven jars of different GAVC and dependencies. Instead of each team having to manually create their own POM.xml I want to let them only customize the build job parameters when they instantiate it. Aside from that, even if all variables were "set in stone", I would still need to supply `version` by the build (the third number corresponds to the build number).

Comment: I have read a little about maven archetypes and it seems they could be what I am looking for, each build would run `archetype:generate` and then run "standard" maven on the created pom.xml file.

Comment: Hi @MartinMelka, if this issue is resolved. could you please post the updated pom file/answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the replacer-plugin. Please see the Internet for more detailed usage of the plugin.

**WARNING 1:**                    I do not think replacing artifactId is a strategy that is maintainable. But it's your choice.

**WARNING 2:** Only define this plugin inside a profile that only gets activated on this specific build. Otherwise this plugin execution gets inherited down to child projects, which could be a bad idea.

Your config should look something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>yourId</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token><![CDATA[<version>[$][{]runtimeVersion[}]</version>]]></token>
                        <value><![CDATA[<version>1.0.42</version>]]></value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```